# Are there any field recording windscreen solutions for DPA 4011-TL stereo set?

Tags: field-recording, wind-protection, windscreens, dpa, windshield

I have a stereo pair of DPA 4011-TLs that I use for instrument recording, but I also want to use them for field recording if possible.  I'm having a hard time finding a blimp or windshield solution that would protect them from the elements and filter out wind.

I'm new to field recording, recently purchased a sound devices mixpre 6 ii, and I have these mics I'd like to use for ambient otrf and/or xy arrangements. I'd appreciate some direction or advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Start your search with "Rycote BBG", short for baby ball gag.